# How to display a graph from temperature, humidity readings?

Tags: temperature

I managed to get my RaspberryPi & DHT 2302 sensor working
I have my readings added to a file every 10 min 
I want to display them now as a graph on my website

What will be an option?

Assumptions:
Graph can be generated using Pi 
Graph can be generated on my external server (if the file will be pushed)

Requirements:
Graph can be selected as: last hour, day, week, month, all
Show average, minimum, maximum

Comment: how looks like your line in file you append? Give a sample line. MRTG could do this.

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably end up using Munin.  It allows for single node or multi-node monitoring of various metrics.  It looks a bit daunting to get it set up (it really isn't) because of the command-line configurations.  The most difficult part of it is getting permissions correct.

In any case, following is the Munin plug-in that I wrote (to run on the RPi) to monitor temperature:

```
 #!/bin/sh

 case $1 in
   config)
    cat <<'EOM'
 graph_title RPi Temperature
 graph_category Temperature
 graph_vlabel temp
 temp.label C
 EOM
    exit 0;;
 esac

 echo -n "temp.value "
 /opt/vc/bin/vcgencmd measure_temp|cut -d'=' -f2|cut -d\' -f1
```

That's all there is to it.  All but the last line is Munin-config related.  The last is the command line to pull in the temperature.

One slight change to your requirements, I believe that Munin gathers metrics every 5 minutes.

Comment: Easy enough to change the sample time for Munin. There will be a cron job on the server. Eg `/etc/crond.d/munin`. Just change the `*/5 * * * * ...` to `*/10 * * * * ...`

Answer (score 0):

Yesterday a user submitted an example of checking RPi temperature from the browser with Plotly (full disclosure: I work there).

You can fork the code here: https://github.com/jensb89/PiTemp.

Here's how the graph looks: https://plot.ly/~jensb89/12/.

Once you've generated your graph, you can embed it as an iframe with this snippet:

```
<iframe id="igraph" src="https://plot.ly/~abhishek.mitra.963/1/400/250/" width="400" height="250" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

You'll want to swap in your URL in the code. Let me know if you have any issues or I can help with anything. Here's how it looks:

[image].